# how to run certain function until we got desired values, python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I  have one for loop by which I am generating some random daily value for each month. I need to make it sure that the generated monthly mean value should equal to the observed mean value (provided in different dataframe). So I need to run this for loop until the desired value is generated and after that it again run for next month.

I have sample code but not sure how to run it several time until to get desired value:

```
for j in np.arange(1,13,1):
    # calculating monthly leanth from provided datasets 
    mlen = ((df_test[df_test.index.year==2000]).index.month==j).sum()

    # fit to my distribution
    phat = stats.exponweib.fit((df_test[df_test.index.month==j].mean(axis=1)).dropna())

    # predicting based on the fitted distribution
    esti = stats.exponweib.rvs(*phat,int(mlen))

    if esti.mean() == monthly_mean[0]
```

Where monthly_mean is the observed monthly mean value is its look like below, where the first value for the first month.

```
monthly_mean = array([  5.15    ,   5.948571,   7.028261,   4.144231,   3.585965,
         5.244828,   4.915455,   4.757   ,   5.803614,  12.573684,
         5.683333,   3.875   ])
```

any help/suggestion is highly appriciated!

Comment: you should use while loop

Comment: @Dipu or 1 more for loop

Comment: @Dipu instead of if or inplace of for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag to check when you have to stop searching

```
flag = True
while (flag):
    for j in np.arange(1,13,1):
        # calculating monthly leanth from provided datasets 
        mlen = ((df_test[df_test.index.year==2000]).index.month==j).sum()

        # fit to my distribution
        phat = stats.exponweib.fit((df_test[df_test.index.month==j].mean(axis=1)).dropna())

        # predicting based on the fitted distribution
        esti = stats.exponweib.rvs(*phat,int(mlen))

        if esti.mean() == monthly_mean[0]:
            flag = False
```

Since you need to check for every month, you can embeed the if in a for loop

```
for month_thingy in monthly_mean:
    if esti.mean() == month_thingy:
        flag = False
```

Comment: bool flag = true
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I afraid that I might be wrong..it seems like it only compares for the first month. I was thinking when it got best match for first month then it should generate for second month so I will have complete datasets for one year

Comment: You can embeed the last condition in a for loop, i'll edit to give you an example

Comment: Thank you @Cid, your help is appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome, the code can be upgraded to avoid useless iterations and makes it more pythonic